# Individual Email Results with guided send are not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

For Journey sends it is super easy to analyse the results in Salesforce Salescloud. We just take a Report Type: Individual Email Results with Lead (for example). 
But how can I analyse the results for a Guided send ? Or User-Initiated Email ?

I really can't find it in any of the reports in SF Salescloud.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, so you need to send them via Salesforce Send Emails under interactions Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom report type in Salesforce SalesCloud and include Required Objects in the custom report

**Objects**
1. Contacts
2. Campaigns
3. Individual Email Results 
4. Individual Link level Details ( to Get the metrics Information)

After Creating Custom report type

Create the Report using that custom report type

You Can able to track the guided send and user initiated emails

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the steps to create a custom report type but still unable to see the guided send and user initiated emails send track. It seems like only journey builder track that I can track. Are you able to see the guided send tracking ? Thanks

Comment: @hamza Did you enable tracking information checks in marketing cloud tab

Comment: Does your tracking data flowing back from MC to Salesforce

Comment: Yes,  tracking information are enable. I can receive tracking on Salesforce by using Journey Builder, but not when using guided send or user-inititated-email?